# Include an S4 object from an existing package as a slot in a new S4 class

Tags: r, class, r-s4

I am writing an S4 class called `Expression` and would like to include an S4 object, `DESeq2 = "DESeqDataSet"` as a slot:

```
setClass(
Class = "Expression",
representation = representation (
    species = "character", 
    edgeR = "DGEList",
    DESeq2 = "DESeqDataSet",
    lengths = "matrix",
    individuals = "vector",
    treatments = "vector",
    id = "vector",
    samples = "vector",
    sample_prep = "vector",
    genome_type = "vector",
    molecule_type = "vector",
    blast_hit =  "vector",
    rRNA = "vector",
    protein = "vector"
))
```

When I check the package, though, I get the following Warning:

```
Found the following significant warnings:
  Warning: undefined slot classes in definition of "Expression": DESeq2(class "DESeqDataSet")
```

The class works fine (ie, there are now errors), but I would like to fix all warnings in our code.

The package with the `DESeqDataSet` object (`DESeq2`, also the name we have given to the slot) is imported in the package `DESCRIPTION` file. Do I need to do something else to make its contents available for use in a slot? For example, I have used `setOldClass()` to make S3 classes available for use in S4 slots.

Here is an example of a travis-ci build that throws the warning - https://travis-ci.org/caseywdunn/agalmar/builds/138564256

The full code that is giving the problem is at https://github.com/caseywdunn/agalmar/blob/a7c4013fcb5c924cfd6e1aa8e99f182ceec6fe20/R/utility_functions.R

Answer (score 5):

Class definitions need to be imported, just like functions, generics, and methods. So in the NAMESPACE file say

```
importClassesFrom("DESeq2", "DESeqDataSet")
```

I believe the roxygen2 notation is `@importClassesFrom DESeq2 DESeqDataSet`

Comment: Incredibly helpful - thanks. I added that roxygen2 line to my class documentation and the warning is gone. Much appreciated.

Comment: I tried this and the error didn't go away. I later found out it was because I did not include `Imports: ....` in the `DESCRIPTION` file manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem by using the "contains" parameter of the setClass function. Contains can define any types or objects.

```
setClass(
Class = "Expression",
representation = representation (
    species = "character", 
    edgeR = "DGEList",
    DESeq2 = "DESeqDataSet",
    lengths = "matrix",
    individuals = "vector",
    treatments = "vector",
    id = "vector",
    samples = "vector",
    sample_prep = "vector",
    genome_type = "vector",
    molecule_type = "vector",
    blast_hit =  "vector",
    rRNA = "vector",
    protein = "vector"
    ), 
    contains = c("DGEList", "DESeqDataSet")
)
```

Hope this helps.