# Extending a S4 class from another package: reconcilePropertiesAndPrototype error

Tags: r, extends, r-s4, roxygen, dbplyr

I am trying to write a subclass for `RJDBC::JDBCConnection` as I need custom methods to connect the `dbplyr` package using the approach from [dplyr#2941](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2941#issue-240495102) (originally [from here](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/05/17/databases-using-r/#comment-3389121188)). However, I am not overwriting the `*.JDBCConnection` methods but want to write methods for a subclass of `JDBCConnection`.

Therefore, following the advise from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37901161/3082472), I wrote my package which is essentially this:

```
### R/testclass.R ####################
#' Test class
#'
#' This extends JDBCConnection in package RJDBC
#'
#' @import RJDBC
#'
setClass("TestConnection", contains = "JDBCConnection")

### DESCRIPTION ######################
Package: test
Type: Package
Title: What the Package Does (Title Case)
Version: 0.1.0
Author: Who wrote it
Maintainer: The package maintainer <yourself@somewhere.net>
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
    Use four spaces when indenting paragraphs within the Description.
License: What license is it under?
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
```

The class I want to extend exists, as can be checked with `help("JDBCConnection-class", package = "RJDBC")`.

Calling `devtools::document()` within this packages returns the following error:

> ```
> Updating test documentation
> Loading test
>
> Error in reconcilePropertiesAndPrototype(name, slots, prototype, superClasses,  : 
> no definition was found for superclass "JDBCConnection" in the specification of class "TestConnection"
> ```

I also tried replacing `@import` with `@importClassesFrom` [as per this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37901161/3082472), but the result was the same.

How can I get `document()` to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to add

```
Imports: RJDBC
```

to your `DESCRIPTION` file. See, for example, [this guide](http://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/depends.html):

> If your package is using functions in other packages, you also need to
>   add some lines to your DESCRIPTION file.
>
> ...
>
> Imports is used for packages that are needed by your package but that
>   don’t need to be loaded with library(). Packages referred to in
>   @import or @importFrom statements in your Roxygen2 comments, or whose
>   functions are accessed via the :: operator, should be here.

After that, your package `document()`'d fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

I succeeded to document the package when I do not rely on `roxygen2` to write my `DESCRIPTION` file but add the packages myself. `NAMESPACE` is managed by `roxygen2`.

If I add the Line

```
Imports: methods, RJDBC
```

or

```
Depends: RJDBC
```

to the `DESCRIPTION` file manually, `devtools::document()` runs without error.

[*duckmayr found it out in the same time*]